# segmentation fault core dumped using ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

I wrote a code to read a text file and do  some processes on that. It was working properly on my own PC and another Linux system. However, when I run it on a different Linux system I get "segmentation fault (core dumped)" error for the "ifstream" command. I checked the text file and if it is too small e.g. two lines, the cose works fine but when the file is larger e.g. 20 lines, it crashes with the segmentation fault error.

The piece of the code causing error:

```
int ExtractFragments(int fragmentLength, int overlappingResidues)
{

string line = "", lines = "", interfaceFileName = "";

ifstream interfaceList("tempInterfaceList.txt"); 
if (interfaceList)
{

    bool errFlag = false;

    while (getline(interfaceList, interfaceFileName))   
    {
        cout << endl << "interfaces/" << interfaceFileName;
        ifstream interfaceFile("interface.txt");    //This line crashes

        if (interfaceFile)
            cout << "\nHello";
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Any ideas why this ifsream causing segmentation fault and how to solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: What do your command line arguments look like?

Comment: A [mcve] would be good...

Comment: Debuggers are great for this.  `gdb <binary name>`, `run <program options>`, `backtrace`

Comment: @Brandon fragmentLength is 4 and overlappingResidues is 3.

Comment: @F.Hl Which are not used anywhere. Is that really the code that fails? Plus what is the other OS? And what compiler you use?

Comment: @Paul R The interface.txt file is a Protein Data Bank (PDB) formatted file like: ATOM   7896  CA  THR C 110      60.167  84.528  10.368  1.00 28.21           C  
ATOM   7903  CA  LEU C 111      57.630  86.816  12.058  1.00 26.74           C

Comment: @freakish The other OS was Windows. I am running the code on the school clusters. I am using the command  g++ -std=c++11 for compiling my codes.

Comment: @F.HI i ran the exact same program on my VM running ubuntu and have used test PDB file contents and it works as expected for 20 or more lines.

Comment: @F.HI if you are using the same file for windows and linux, don't, they have different line endings. make sure you create both the text and PDB files and save them in the target machine. If that doesn't work, it may be hard to find the problem.

Comment: @Suraj S Thanks. Yes it is working on some computers properly. I don't know how to solve this problem on this specific computer.

Comment: @Suraj S OK I will try it. However, I think the files were created in Linux. Thanks.

Comment: @SurajS It's unlikely that `ifstream` would segfault in that case.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect Concurrent access to the same stream may introduce data races. you are opening a file in input mode in while loop there you must handle the exception

```
      int ExtractFragments(int fragmentLength, int overlappingResidues)
    {

        ifstream interfaceList("tempInterfaceList.txt"); 
interfaceList.exceptions ( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );

try

  {

        if ( interfaceFile.fail() ) 
          {
            return -1;
          }

         bool errFlag = false;

        while (getline(interfaceList, interfaceFileName))   
        {
            cout << endl << "interfaces/" << interfaceFileName;
            ifstream interfaceFile("interface.txt");    //This line crashes

            if (interfaceFile)
                cout << "\nHello";
        }
    }

   catch(std::ifstream::failure &FileExcep)
        {
           cout<<FileExcep.what()<<endl;
            return -1;

        }
        catch(...)
        {
            cout<< "other exception thrown"<<endl
            return -1;
        }

      return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Rohini Singh I tried it but the same error again.

Comment: I tired by putting more than 1000 line in both the files .all is good here 
I think you should use gdb to debug the core it might be intermediate issues
YOu should use efficient string parsing and error handling using exceptions

Comment: I request downvoters to explain the reason why downvote pls